# Better method structure for insertion in doubly linked list (Java)

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Here is my insertion method for doubly linked list. It works but passing two parameters for the method seems cumbersome. Anyone can suggest a cleaner approach than this?

Code
            // Execution example
            MyLinkedList list = new MyLinkedList();
            Link link1 = new Link("A");
            list.insert(list.head,link1);
            Link link2 = new Link("B");
            list.insert(link1, link2);
            Link link3 = new Link("C");
            list.insert(link2, link3);
            list.display_List_Start_From_Head();

```
public void insert(Link currentNode, Link newNode)
    {
        if(head == null)
        {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            currentNode.next = newNode;
            newNode.prev = currentNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }


    }


public class MyLinkedList {

    public Link head;
    public Link tail;
    public Link currentNode;
    public Link newNode;

    public MyLinkedList()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }


public class Link {

    public String data;
    public Link prev;
    public Link next;

    public Link(String data)
    {
        this(data,null,null);
    }

    public Link(String data, Link prev, Link next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.prev = prev;
        this.next = next;
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you want to make it simpler and just loop through the structure to find the end, or could you have the list in a structure that keeps track of the last node?  You may find that this is why binary trees are useful, as you can insert into the correct spot, so it is sorted.

Comment: Probably codereview (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the best place to ask this question.

Comment: @JamesBlack are you suggesting passing the LinkedList as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void insert(Link newNode)
{
    if(head == null)
    {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        tail.next = newNode;
        newNode.prev = tail;
        tail = newNode;
    }

}
```

BTW, rename your class because `LinkedList` is too similar to `java.util.LinkedList`

Comment: I just renamed my class. Great suggestion and implementation!

Answer (score 1):

If you are appending to the end of the `LinkedList`, then you can just set `list.head.prev.next = newLink`, `newLink.next = list.head`, `newLink.prev = list.head.prev` and `list.head.prev = newLink`.

Comment: I notice you did not update the tail during the insertion. Why did you wrote it like that?

Comment: I am not sure about the specific implementation of OP's `LinkedList` class - all I know for sure is that he has a pointer to the `head` element.